# Google Sheets =IMPORTHTML runs on load then "could not fetch url"

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make a Market calculator for Old School Rune Scape and I'm running into problems with using the IMPORTHTML function of google sheets.

I use the following to pull data from an online table.

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/results?query=bronze&minPrice=0&maxPrice=-1&members=no&page=1#main-search", "table", 1)
```

This will work, however, after a few minutes it no longer updates and throws up

> "Could not fetch url: http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/results?query=iron&minPrice=0&maxPrice=-1&members=no&page=2#main-search"

I've found that by deleting the "=" from the start of the cell and then adding it back in, the data will repopulate. 
Is there a way to force update this function? Or perhaps a different function that would work better for this application?

Answer (score -1):

try like this:

```
=IFERROR(
 IMPORTHTML("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/results?query=bronze&minPrice=0&maxPrice=-1&members=no&page=1#main-search", 
 "table", 1), 
 IMPORTHTML("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/results?query=bronze&minPrice=0&maxPrice=-1&members=no&page=1#main-search", 
 "table", 1))
```

or even:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(
 IMPORTHTML("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/results?query=bronze&minPrice=0&maxPrice=-1&members=no&page=1#main-search", 
 "table", 1), 
 IMPORTHTML("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/results?query=bronze&minPrice=0&maxPrice=-1&members=no&page=1#main-search", 
 "table", 1)), 
 IMPORTHTML("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/results?query=bronze&minPrice=0&maxPrice=-1&members=no&page=1#main-search", 
 "table", 1))
```